# Is it possible for a Spring CrudRepository that have multiple saves

Tags: java, spring

I have the following repository that lets me get a number of different entities that are closely related, but small enough I'd rather not have each of them in their own repos. Due do how some of these are saved some are saved through cascading of parent Aggs, and the other is manually saved by a call to save(fooBar);

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface FooBarRepository extends CrudRepository<FooBar, Long> {
    FooBar findBySomeField(SomeField somefield);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM SomeCloselyRelatedFooBarItem p")
    public List<SomeCloselyRelatedFooBarItem > findAllSomeCloselyRelatedItem();
}
```

I now have a new one that needs to be manually saved as well, and I was hoping to avoid having to create a new repo just for this item, since it's closely related, and will only be used in conjunction with FooBar, but doesn't have a direct relationship to FooBar

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface FooBarRepository extends CrudRepository<FooBar, Long> {
    FooBar findBySomeField(SomeField somefield);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM ConceptuallyRelatedToFooBarButSavedThroughCascade p")
    public List<ConceptuallyRelatedToFooBarButSavedThroughCascade> findAllConceptuallyRelatedToFooBarButSavedThroughCascade();

    public OtherItem save(OtherItem otherItem); //Springs doesn't like this because it's looking for a field on FooBar called save.
}
```

but Spring doesn't like this because it's looking for a field called save on FooBar. @Query doesn't work because there is not insert concept. I've tried naming save another name to hopefully get around it, but that didn't work either. Is the only way around this having to create a whole new repo, or can one repo save multiple entities?

Comment: Why don't you create a specific repo? (that's how it works btw)

Comment: Mainly because it starts to be a pain to have to pass a bunch of different repo to domain services so they can each make one call. There are ways around it, but I was trying to keep things simple.